# STL instruction and memory observers

Tags: arm, arm64, memory-barriers

Does STL instruction ensures that all observers will observe load/stores which placed in program order before STL instruction, I mean does it work as DMB?

Comment: Looks like STL doesn't work as DMB since it is single-copy atomic instruction.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading, it performs a store, then a store-store barrier on the share-ability domain encoded by the pte of the store address.  It seems an improvement to free the program from having to know which domain a given address corresponds to, or needlessly using the outermost (slowest) barrier.